# Address not available Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?

Tags: postgresql, docker, pgadmin, docker-for-windows

I am using PostgreSQL 14.4 inside Docker, and pgAdmin inside Docker for Windows.

My command I used

```
docker run -d --name vy_posgres_for_acc -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres -e POSTGRES_USER=postgres -e PGDATA=D:\docker_mount\postgres\data postgres:latest


docker run -d -p 5050:80 -e PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=donhuvy@hotmail.com -e PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=postgres dpage/pgadmin4:latest

# Go to http://localhost:5050/login PG admin 6.10
```

Error of pgAdmin

```
Address not available Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

How to fix it?

Comment: Seemly I need create Docker network, but my skill in Docker is little. Please guide me use Docker network for this case.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have multiple containers you want to use together, one way to handle things like this is to use [Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/). You create a Compose file, which is a YAML file declaring your containers. When you use `docker compose` to start them, it will create a network for you containing all the containers. They'll then be able to access each other by host name (which defaults to the service name you use in the Compose file).